# Order of reactions in kinetics

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics

In kinetics, zero order reactions are those reactions who are independent from the concentration of the reactant or the product. So their rate is equal to the constant **k**. But still we build the diagram where we find the correlation between concentration and time, where the slope is negative. 
Why do we even write a diagram to find the correlation between **concentration** and time, since these reactions are completely independent from concentration ?

Comment: How would you know the correlation between concentration and  time is of zero order until you draw the diagram?

Answer (score 4):

> So their rate is equal to the constant k.

With other words, the **change** of concentration over time is linear:

\[ \frac{d[\ce{A}]}{dt} = k\]

Comment: So is that the answer ?